# Installing openssl in ruby / rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openssl, rbenv

I need to use openssl in ruby. How should I install the same? I've installed ruby through rbenv, and am using ubuntu 12.04.

```
kprakasam@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]

kprakasam@ubuntu:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'openssl'
LoadError: no such file to load -- openssl
    from /home/kprakasam/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/kprakasam/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/kprakasam/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I think you have to compile ruby with openssl

Comment: `sudo apt-get -y build-essential install zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev` than install ruby again with rbenv, and you will have openssl support

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`openssl` needs to be installed on your local machine.

You then need to compile Ruby with openssl support, which is achieved via the `--with-openssl-dir` command-line switch.

Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/1200482) will help you.

Comment: Then I face the following error - 
`Error running '__rvm_make -j4'`

Answer (score 44):

For Mac OSX this is what saved me:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=<openssl install dir> rbenv install
```

From the [Ruby build wiki](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#missing-openssl)

But.. how to find the *openssl install dir*?:

```
$ brew list openssl
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/bin/c_rehash
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/bin/openssl
...
```

Then the *openssl install dir* is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/
```

And the ruby installation command ends as this:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/ rbenv install
```

Comment: I'll add that my compilation error on OSX mentioned two versions of openssl, I then removed all versions of openssl from brew (uninstall and prune) and reinstalled openssl. Then compiling worked with `ruby-install ruby 2.5.1 -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1/`.

Comment: Fixes `/tmp/ruby-build.20190501225018.25089/ruby-2.6.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in \`require': libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /tmp/ruby-build.20190501225018.25089/ruby-2.6.3/.ext/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)` on Debian 9 as well

Comment: Thank you! also fixes "Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed."

Comment: `brew --prefix openssl@1.1` can be used to get the openssl path, i.e. `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)`

Comment: Unrecognised command, it just opens help on how to use flags. I copied the command exactly.

Answer (score 16):

## Ubuntu

(and other linux distros)

```
$ # Display the installation directory:
$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"

$ # May need to uninstall the previous installation:
$ rbenv uninstall 3.1.2
rbenv: remove /home/aidan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2? [yN] Y

$ # Then reinstall (using the dir from the first step)
$ RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/ssl rbenv install 3.1.2 
Installing ruby-3.1.2...
Installed ruby-3.1.2 to /home/aidan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks. For ruby 2.4.4 the dir of first command did not work. I had to do `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr rbenv install 2.4.4` instead

Answer (score 11):

First, install openssl:

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Afterwards, recompile Ruby.

Note: Only fixing the comment from @Nebojsa above

Comment: This worked for me when installing ruby-2.0.0-p451 from source onto Ubuntu-Saucy 13.10.

Comment: I have upgraded my ubuntu to version 20.04.1 and my ruby stopped working. Using this command and reinstalling the ruby versions on my rbenv did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This might help you: [Rails: cannot load such file — openssl](http://www.dinduks.com/rails-cannot-load-such-file-openssl).

Comment: This is useful if you're using RVM. See the accepted answer if using RBENV.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Please note that this answer may be out of date. The [issue in question](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/issues/387) was resolved in [v0.8.1](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#081--2020-12-20).

---

After reading multiple answers to this question, I managed to get it working on macOS 10.15 using the following commands:

```sh
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
OPENSSL_1_0_DIR=$(brew --prefix rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0)

export CPPFLAGS=-I${OPENSSL_1_0_DIR}/include
export LDFLAGS=-L${OPENSSL_1_0_DIR}/lib

ruby-install ruby 2.2.10 -- --with-openssl-dir=${OPENSSL_1_0_DIR}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on an M2 mac with two versions of openssl installed via Brew (1.1 & 3).

I set an env var for the `--with-openssl-dir` with version 1.1's path.

fish:

```
set -gx RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS "--with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1"
```

bash/zsh:

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1"
```

The build succeeded after the export for me.

*Note:* That I also exported corresponding `CPPFLAGS` & `LDFLAGS`  for the compiler.

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1
export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include
```